# mvn -v command will exit current batch script

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, maven-3

I have a build script written in Batch file which calls maven - it will report the maven version and run the build.

```
@setlocal

mvn -version
mvn clean package
```

The issue is the `mvn -version` command will output and it will exit the script which will not execute further steps. One way to fix this is to change it to `call mvn -version` - it just feels weird to do it this way.

Is this bug in the maven, or am I doing something wrong?
How come it exits the script?

---

I have maven 3.6.3 and I tried it running with Oracle Java 1.8.0_211 and Corretto 8 JDK 1.8.0_252.

Comment: If `mvn` is a batch file, then yes you have to use `CALL`.  That is how cmd.exe works.  If you execute another batch file from a batch file it will pass control to the batch file that is being executed.  The only way to stop that from happening is to use `CALL`.

Comment: I see, as it is actually `mvn.cmd` which is called, it can exit the parent script. I'm wondering now if maven behaved like this always, or it is a bug...

Comment: As far as cmd.exe is concerned, you exited your script when you invoked mvn without a call.